# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get ng-repeat to repeat a list of items, spiffs, in a receipt. I have the edit function of this working but I can't get the add page to work because it reads:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'spiffs' of undefined
```

Here is the code causing it:

```
$scope.model.spiffs = [];
$scope.model.spiffs = [{ spiff_id: 0, receipt_id: 0, product_id: 0, spiff_amt:0, quantity: 1, active: true, note: null }];
```

At first it was the second line but I thought I'd try making the $scope.model an empty array to try and declare the array ahead of time, I tried different variations of this and I think I'm just missing something simple. What do I need to do to setup my form to ng-repeat a set of fields when I don't have any initial input to populate it with? And after that, will I be able to grab all the form data with a simple `$scope.model` call and send it to my API?

Here is the hope-to-be effected HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2" ng-repeat="item in model.spiffs">

  <div ng-hide="item.active === false">
   <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
        <select name="productID"  ng-model="item.product_id" required="" ng-change="changeSpiffProduct($index)" class="form-control"
        ng-options="product.product_id as product.model_number + ' ' + product.name for product in products">
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
          <input name="spiff_sale_price" type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="item.quantity" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
          <p name="spiff_amt" class="form-control-static">{{item.spiff_amt | currency: "$"}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
          <p name="spiff_total" class="form-control-static">{{item.spiff_amt * item.quantity | currency: "$"}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" novalidate ng-click="removeSpiff($index)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: We need to see your controller and where `$scope.model.spiffs` comes from to give you proper advice.

Comment: It suppose to display TypeError: Cannot set property 'spiffs' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the property "model" of your scope first before you can assign "spiff" to it. You can do that in two ways:

```js
$scope.model = {};

//OR:

$scope.model = {
  spiffs: []
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing $scope.model.spiffs. Here model is undefined, hence the error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'spiffs' of undefined

You need to initialize $scope.model first, like this

> $scope.model = {}

Now since $scope.model is not undefined, you can add a property.

Hope it helps.